# Existence of tubular neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a subset of $X$. My understanding of a tubular neighborhood $N$ of $A$ is that $N$ is an open set containing 
$A$ such that $\bar N$ is a manifold with boundary which deformation retracts onto $A$. Is my understanding of tubular neighborhoods correct? and what are the more general conditions we put on $X$ such that a tubular neighborhood exists? i mean by googling i read that when $X$ is a manifold and $A$ is a compact submanifold than such a tubular neighborhood $N$ exists, but what about more general spaces like CW-complexes and so on? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Your understanding is pretty much right, but I would add a few things.

For $N$ to be a tubular neighborhood, it's not enough to require that $N$ is open and its closure is a manifold with boundary (you meant $\bar{N}$, not $\bar{A}$, right?).  You also want it to be nicely imbedded locally into $X$.  Wikipedia and Mathworld both describe this pretty well.

Any tubular neighborhood (not just one) should have the deformation retract property you mention.  It seems conventional to assume that $X$ is a manifold and $A$ is a submanifold, in which case existence is known.  I don't know about more general existence theorems, but there is a similar concept called a "regular neighborhood" of a subcomplex in a piecewise linear manifold.  See, for example, Hempel's book on three-manifolds.